# React component is going under another component

Tags: css, reactjs, layout, material-ui, frontend

The blue area in the picture attached is the "main" component. It is going under the Navigation bar, as you can see in the following image:

[image]

I am using Material-ui v3 for styling. I don't think this is the issue with z-index. I tried everything but the issue not resolved.Does anyone know the solution??

```
const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        width: '100%',
    },
    grow: {
        flexGrow: 1,
    },
    menuButton: {
        marginLeft: -12,
        marginRight: 20,
    },
    appBar: {
        color: '#3D4042',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        fontFamily: 'Sen',
    },
    toolBar: {
        margin: [[0, '2%']],
        padding: 16,
    },
    navList: {
        listStyle: 'none',
        display: 'inline',
        marginLeft: 16,
        marginRight: 16
    },
    sectionDesktop: {
        display: 'none',
        [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
            display: 'flex',
        },
    },
    sectionMobile: {
        display: 'flex',
        [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
            display: 'none',
        },
    },
});

const NavBar = (props) => {
    const { classes } = props;
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
    const [mobileMoreAnchorEl, setMobileMoreAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

    const isMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);
    const isMobileMenuOpen = Boolean(mobileMoreAnchorEl);

    const handleProfileMenuOpen = (event) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const handleMobileMenuClose = () => {
        setMobileMoreAnchorEl(null);
    };

    const handleMenuClose = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
        handleMobileMenuClose();
    };

    const handleMobileMenuOpen = (event) => {
        setMobileMoreAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };

    const menuId = 'primary-search-account-menu';
    const renderMenu = (
        <Menu
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
            id={menuId}
            keepMounted
            transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
            open={isMenuOpen}
            onClose={handleMenuClose}
        >
            <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={handleMenuClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    );

    const mobileMenuId = 'primary-search-account-menu-mobile';
    const renderMobileMenu = (
        <Menu
            anchorEl={mobileMoreAnchorEl}
            anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
            id={mobileMenuId}
            keepMounted
            transformOrigin={{ vertical: 'top', horizontal: 'right' }}
            open={isMobileMenuOpen}
            onClose={handleMobileMenuClose}
        >
            <MenuItem>
                <IconButton aria-label="show 4 new mails" color="inherit">
                    <Badge badgeContent={4} color="secondary">
                        <MailIcon />
                    </Badge>
                </IconButton>
                <p>Messages</p>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>
                <IconButton aria-label="show 11 new notifications" color="inherit">
                    <Badge badgeContent={11} color="secondary">
                    <NotificationsIcon />
                    </Badge>
                </IconButton>
                <p>Notifications</p>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={handleProfileMenuOpen}>
                <IconButton
                    aria-label="account of current user"
                    aria-controls="primary-search-account-menu"
                    aria-haspopup="true"
                    color="inherit"
                >
                    <AccountCircle />
                </IconButton>
                <p>Profile</p>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    );
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <AppBar position="static" className={classes.appBar}>
                <Toolbar className='wrapper toolbar'>
                    <div className="">
                        <img className='logo' src={logo} alt="logo"/>
                    </div>

                    <div className={classes.sectionDesktop}>
                        <div className='navItems'>
                            <div className="">
                                <ul style={{display: 'inline'}}>
                                    <li className={classes.navList}> Home </li>
                                    <li className={classes.navList}> Features </li>
                                    <li className={classes.navList}> Pricing </li>
                                    <li className={classes.navList}> FAQ </li>
                                    <li className={classes.navList}> Contact </li>
                                </ul>
                                <a href="#" className={clsx('empBtton', 'unoBtton')}>
                                    <span>
                                        Employer
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" className={clsx('empBtton', 'unoBtton')}>
                                    <span>
                                        Employee
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <button className={clsx('signupButton', 'unoBtton')}>
                                Signup
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className={classes.sectionMobile}>
                        <IconButton className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" onClick={handleMobileMenuOpen}>
                            <MenuIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                    </div>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
            {renderMenu}
            {renderMobileMenu}
        </div>

    );
}


NavBar.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(NavBar);

// export default NavBar;
```

```
const styles = theme => ({
    heroContainer: {
        zIndex: 2000
    },
    heroTitle: {
        fontSize: 40,
        color: 'rgb(37, 39, 40)',
        marginBottom: 32
    },
    heroText: {
        color: '#6E7477',
        fontSize: 20
    },
    heroTextContainer: {
        marginTop: 125,
        marginBottom: 135
    }
});

// const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
//     heroContainer: {
//         paddingTop: 32,
//         paddingBottom: 60,
//         margin: [[0, '4%']],
//     },
//     heroTitle: {
//         fontSize: 40,
//         fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
//         color: 'rgb(37, 39, 40)',
//         marginBottom: 32
//     },
//     heroText: {
//         color: '#6E7477',
//         fontSize: 20
//     },
//     heroTextContainer: {
//         marginTop: 125,
//         marginBottom: 135
//     }
// }));

const Main = (props) => {
    const { classes } = props;
    return (
        <div className={clsx(classes.heroContainer, 'wrapper')}>
            <Grid container spacing={4}>
                <Grid item xs={12} lg={5} className={classes.heroTextContainer}>
                    <div>
                        <Typography variant="h4" className={classes.heroTitle}>
                            Simplest way to manage household employees
                        </Typography>
                        <p className={classes.heroText}>
                            unoHR is a simple and easy to use household employee management application
                            that can be entirely run on smartphones and tablets.
                        </p>
                        <br/> <br/>
                        <span style={ { 'font-size': '15px', 'color': '#6E7477' } }> On-boarding |Task Manager |  Timesheets | Payroll | Tax Filings </span>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                    </div>

                    <div style={ { 'margin-top': '32px' } }>
                        <img style={ {width: 148,'margin-right': '8px' } } src="http://uno.surge.sh/static/app-store-e91688a43ed733ae3cb09644705112b7.svg" alt="apple"/>
                        <img style={ {width: 163 } } src="http://uno.surge.sh/static/google-play-ae5962682f9c55fd1d9a47392977a5c3.svg" alt="android"/>
                    </div>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12} lg={7} style={{'overflow': 'hidden'}}>
                    <img style={ {'max-width': '700px', 'object-fit': 'fit'} } className={classes.maxWidth} src={mobile} alt="mobile"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

        </div>
    );
}

Main.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Main);
```

Comment: I guess from what you share you can solve this by adding a margin-top to the element that is bellow but I am not sure. Can you try this?